# Problem in filling table of ArcSDE feature class in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arcgis-desktop, feature-class

I have an ArcSDE point feature class and I add it to ArcMap 10.

After that I add some points to it and fill every field for all points in the attribute table and Save Editing.

However, the SQL Server table that related to the feature class is empty while the attribute table in ArcMap and ArcCatalog is full (as expected).

I checked the connection to the spatial database and that was correct.

How do I fill the table in SQL Server when the attribute table in ArcGIS is full?

Answer (score 2):

If your feature class is registered as versioned in SDE the changes are held in your "delta" tables until you compress your database. If you are looking at the tables in SQL server you will see A## and D## tables. These tables are the " delta" tables and the number part is the number that was registered to your feature class when you created it in SDE. If you look at the tables in your SQL database you will see an sde_registered_tables ( or something very similar). That is where you'll find the number assigned to your particular feature class. So, in summary, changes in a versioned feature class are held in separate tables until compressed. ArcGIS collects the base features and changes (base table--your feature class, A## and D## tables) to deliver the current state of your features. The display and attributes of the 3 tables is seen as one result and delivered to the client (ArcMap, Server, etc). Your work is not lost, you'll simply need to compress. If your features are part of another version, not default, you'll need to reconcile and post your changes to promote them to the parent version and then compress. The compress process merges all of the changes into the base table.

Comment: Another way to view your versioned data through SQL is by using a versioned view. They allow you to see the current state of your data on different versions.  As 18059 was saying, they collect the base features and changes into one result set.  This means that you don't always have to do a compress. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006z0000000q000000